Using OPENJSON to get a Key Pair List
With the JSON below, I want to retrieve a key pair list of Parameter Names and Parameter Values. I don't want to hardcode anything as the parameters will change.
I have two queries that return the results I want but the first one has a worse execution plan.
Is either of these the best option, or is there another, better way to achieving what I'm after?
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{ "SearchParameters": [ { "LastName": "Smith" }, { "Org": "AAA" }, { "Postcode": "SW1" } ] }';

SELECT z.[key], z.value
FROM OPENJSON(@json) x
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(x.value) y
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(y.value) z

SELECT 
    (SELECT [key] FROM OPENJSON([value])) AS KeyName,
    (SELECT [value] FROM OPENJSON([value])) AS KeyValue
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [value]
     FROM 
         OPENJSON(@json,'$.SearchParameters') 
    ) x


You may use a CROSS APPLY
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{ "SearchParameters": [ { "LastName": "Smith" }, { "Org": "AAA" }, { "Postcode": "SW1" } ] }';

SELECT k.[key] AS ParameterName, k.value AS ParameterValue
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.SearchParameters') AS p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(p.value) AS k;

